# AI with un-enumerable action output?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm getting into AI as a hobby and all of my previous projects had the action output enumerated and specific choices however the new project I want to begin working on will require for example the AI to decide the best place to tap on a screen. Can anyone point me some resources/information that I can research to learn this task? I just need to know what to search to educate myself.

Comment: may be see http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/shi17a/shi17a.pdf

Comment: To be more specific, I'm wanting to make a CNN that can play a strategy phone game and it will need to learn the best place to put a unit for example

Comment: I am not sure that this is an *un-enumerable* problem. Doesn't your screen have a fixed number of pixels that the agent can tap on?

Comment: That's a way of looking that I didn't expect. I'll give it a shot and see what happens, thanks!